# Connecting to CPanel Database

Tags: mysql, database, cpanel

i'm trying to connect to a **CPanel** database on a remote server from my Laptop's SequelPro, it's not working and i have no idea why, i've set the remote access to be the '`%`' wildcard, so my specific machine shouldn't matter

I'm using the **domain name** of the site and i've used the correct username and password for a user i created on my CPanel's DB... what am i doing wrong? Or am i overlooking some detail?
It should just login with the domain and user credentials right?

Answer (score 0):

Please ask your hosting providers if they do allow remote mysql connections to their mysql server. Most of the providers don't. You could test that by doing a telnet connection on the mysql server's ip address, portt 3306.

```
telnet mysql-server-ip 3306
```

If you can connect then they do allow incoming mysql connections from the internet to their server. If not, then there is nothing you can do. Just write them, explain your problem and see what they say.

Login to cPanel and go to MySQL Databases. Check if there's any remote mysql server shown there. If not, most probably the MySQL runs locally on the cPanel server the mysql server ip = the cPanel server ip. If you go to
cPanel -> Remote MySQL you can add there your ip address or the ip you're connecting to. That might fix your issue...

Comment: How do you get the `mysql-server-ip`

Comment: I've updated my answer with extra info related to your comment.